# When i use time.sleep it pauses it early

Tags: python, time, pygame

The time.sleep is at the end but somehow it the code starts with time.sleep first. I want it to pick a random name then wait for 30 seconds. After 30 secounds i want it to pick a random number from 0 to 100. This is for two players. I want it too display the 2 names first then wait for 30 secs then show 2 random numbers bellow the player 1 and player 2 text

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
import random
import time
import delay
pygame.init()
Red = (247, 12, 12)
White = (255,255,255)
Blue = (0, 157, 255)
Person_One = random.randint(0,19)
Person_Two = random.randint(0,19)
Number1 = random.randint(0,100)
Number2 = random.randint(0,100)
mmm =  ["Donald", "Jacey","Baxter","Dusan","Nathaniel","Hayden","Yusuf","Hayley","Andre","Rafif","Jeremey","Mark","Tia","Malu","Dorian","Jarius","Sammar","Peter","Rafif","Jasmin"]
Playerone = mmm[Person_One]
Playertwo = mmm[Person_Two]
X = 400
timer = 0
Y = 300
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y))
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)
text = font.render("Player one is:", True, Red, Blue)
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (X // 4.4, Y // 3.6)
text1 = font.render(Playerone, True, Red, Blue)
text1Rect = text1.get_rect()
text1Rect.center = (X // 4.4, Y // 3)
text2 = font.render("Player two is:", True, Red, Blue)
text2Rect = text2.get_rect()
text2Rect.center = (X // 1.5, Y // 3.6)
text3 = font.render(Playertwo, True, Red, Blue)
text3Rect = text3.get_rect()
text3Rect.center = (X // 1.5, Y // 3)
aa = True
while True:
 
    # completely fill the surface object
    # with white color
    display_surface.fill(White)
 
    # copying the text surface object
    # to the display surface object
    # at the center coordinate.
    display_surface.blit(text, textRect)
    display_surface.blit(text1, text1Rect)
    display_surface.blit(text2, text2Rect)
    display_surface.blit(text3, text3Rect)
    aa = False
    Number2=str(Number2)
    text3 = font.render(Number2, True, Red, Blue)
    text3Rect = text3.get_rect()
    text3Rect.center = (X // 1.5, Y // 3)
    
    display_surface.blit(text3, text3Rect)
    time.sleep(20)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the program sleeping before the call to display.update. Things are only displayed when this is called, so it waits 20 seconds.  Move display.update above the sleep call.